Reversing the order of column names that contain both numbers and letters in R
I have a data set (df) with  many columns,  the names of which contain letters and numbers. For example
pr.2013 pr.2012 pr. 2011 cd.2013 cd.2012 cd.2011 and so on  and I want to order them alphabetically to this format
cd.2013 cd.2012 cd.2011 pr.2013 pr.2012 pr. 2011
I tried
df1<-df %>% select(order(colnames(.))) 

but with no success. Is there any way to do that in R. Manually is not an option as I have a large number of similar columns.
Many thanks in advance!

It sounds like you want the alphabetic prefix part to be reversed, but the numeric part to stay in ascending order?

This is basically equivalent to Sorting a Vector in R with Mixed Alphanumeric and Non-Alphanumeric Strings if you remove decreasing = TRUE from the first order() call and add it to the second one.

If this is your data
  pr.2012 pr.2011 pr.2013 cd.2012 cd.2013 cd.2011
1       1       2       3       4       5       6
2       2       3       4       5       6       7
3       3       4       5       6       7       8

Using the strsplit by . and arranged colnames to select the variables in the right order.
library(dplyr)

df[,match(data.frame(t(data.frame(strsplit(colnames(df), "\\.")))) %>% 
    arrange(X1, desc(X2)) %>% 
    reframe(paste0(X1, ".", X2)) %>% 
    unlist(use.names=F), colnames(df))]
  cd.2013 cd.2012 cd.2011 pr.2013 pr.2012 pr.2011
1       5       4       6       3       1       2
2       6       5       7       4       2       3
3       7       6       8       5       3       4

Data
df <- structure(list(pr.2012 = 1:3, pr.2011 = 2:4, pr.2013 = 3:5, cd.2012 =
 4:6, cd.2013 = 5:7, cd.2011 = 6:8), class = "data.frame", row.names =
 c(NA, -3L))


thank you but I have too many columns so this code is not  very useful

What does the number of columns have to do with the code?

sorry you are absolutely right!

I get this error message  Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 4, 8

Maybe one or more colnames do not have a dot . as a separator (or more than one). It's splitting the names by the dot and all names should have the form "letters"."digits".

We assume

the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end
that we want to sort by the prefix (part before dot)
we wish to maintain the same order for the suffix (part after the dot)

Note that the tools package comes with R so it does not have to be installed.
library(dplyr)
library(tools)

ix <- dat %>% names %>% file_path_sans_ext %>% order
dat %>% select(all_of(ix))

##   cd.2013 cd.2012 cd.2011 pr.2013 pr.2012 pr.2011
## 1       4       5       6       1       2       3

Note
Input data frame shown reproducibly.
dat <- data.frame(pr.2013 = 1L, pr.2012 = 2L, pr.2011 = 3L, 
  cd.2013 = 4L, cd.2012 = 5L, cd.2011 = 6L)


You can use order + sub like below
> x <- c("pr.2013", "pr.2012", "pr. 2011", "cd.2013", "cd.2012", "cd.2011")

> x[order(sub("\\..*", "", x))]
[1] "cd.2013"  "cd.2012"  "cd.2011"  "pr.2013"  "pr.2012"  "pr. 2011"


If there's really lots of columns, it might be better to create a separate sorting vector and then simply select accordingly. Try this:
# Pkgs (stringr, tibble, dplyr) -------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data ----------------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~pr.2013, ~pr.2012, ~pr.2011, ~cd.2013, ~cd.2012, ~cd.2011,
        1L,       2L,       3L,       4L,       5L,       6L)

# Sort --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Make a tibble with colnames
# Arrange it by letters fist and descending numbers last
aux <- tibble(value = colnames(my_df)) %>% 
  arrange(str_extract(value, "\\D+"), desc(str_extract(value, "\\d+$"))) %>% 
  pull(value)

# Sort the tibble/df with selection-helper `all_of` or `any_of`
new_df <- select(my_df, all_of(aux))
rm(aux)

# Output ------------------------------------------------------------------
new_df
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   cd.2013 cd.2012 cd.2011 pr.2013 pr.2012 pr.2011
#>     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#> 1       4       5       6       1       2       3

Created on 2024-09-16 with reprex v2.1.0

Here is a base R solution:
df <- data.frame(
  pr.2012 = letters[1:10],
  pr.2013 = letters[11:20],
  cd.2012 = LETTERS[1:10],
  cd.2013 = LETTERS[11:20]
)

print(df)

   pr.2012 pr.2013 cd.2012 cd.2013
1        a       k       A       K
2        b       l       B       L
3        c       m       C       M
4        d       n       D       N
5        e       o       E       O
6        f       p       F       P
7        g       q       G       Q
8        h       r       H       R
9        i       s       I       S
10       j       t       J       T


# order column names alphabetically & reverse order
df <- df[,order(sort(colnames(df),decreasing = T))]

print(df)


   cd.2013 cd.2012 pr.2013 pr.2012
1        K       A       k       a
2        L       B       l       b
3        M       C       m       c
4        N       D       n       d
5        O       E       o       e
6        P       F       p       f
7        Q       G       q       g
8        R       H       r       h
9        S       I       s       i
10       T       J       t       j


Thank you but I want to reverse the  order. See above

Take a look, order reversed!
